# Simple Lastrow code COPIED from others does not work?

Tags: excel, vba

Code clearly opens Workbook and Worksheet (with four rows of data)....but then STOPS at "Lastrow = Cells....."   with Error 91 "Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set."

```html
Dim Lastrow As Long, NumPickups As Integer

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\dads\Downloads\Donation Data.xlsm"

Worksheets("DonationDataQuery").Activate

Lastrow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

NumPickups = Lastrow - 1

Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Lastrow, 22)).Select

Selection.Copy

Windows("test.xlsm").Activate

Range("J1").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Windows("Donation Data.xlsm").Activate
```

Revised code approach based on comment below:

```html
Private Sub GeneratePickupData_Click()

'Open the Donation Data.xlsm and copy the data to this worksheet

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\dads\Downloads\Donation Data.xlsm"
Worksheets("DonationDataQuery").Activate

'covert numbers brought over by Acess as text to numbers

Range("A1:O50").Select
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

Dim Lastrow As Long, NumPickups As Integer

Lastrow = 0
NumPickups = 0

''Lastrow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
Lastrow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

NumPickups = Lastrow - 1

'Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Lastrow, 22)).Select
Range("A1", Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select

Range("A1:V50").Select

Selection.Copy

Windows("Pickup Form Gen 2.xlsm").Activate

Range("J1").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Windows("Donation Data.xlsm").Activate


ActiveSheet.UsedRange.ClearContents

ActiveWorkbook.Save

ActiveWindow.Close
```

Comment: Try:
    Lastrow = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

Comment: Your only using Column 1 or column 22 so you can find the last row in one of those columns.:`lastrow=Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` or `lastrow=cells(rows.count,22).end(xlup).row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sheet doesn't contain a cell with "*" inside it, `Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)` will be null. If you then reference `.Row`, you will get the error you've described.

It appears that you're trying to find the last populated row in the sheet. The code below will give you the last row in column "A" with content:

```
LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
```

Note that if you want to select all items in the sheet, this will give you a range containing all populated cells:

```
Dim allCells As Range
Set allCells = Range("A1", Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
```

Both of these pieces of code were created by recording a macro, selecting cell "A1", and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> respectively. Recording macros is a great way to start any vba function!

Comment: Thanks...replaced the code.  However, now the code stops at "Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Lastrow, 22)).Select" with a 1004 error: Application-Defined or Object-Defined error.  As I step through I notice "LastRow" becomes = 2, yet it should be 4 as I have checked the table of values (4 rows, 22 columns)....this is bazaar!

Comment: Maybe instead of `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Lastrow, 22)).Select` (which looks fine to me anyway), you should use `Range("A1", Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select`...

Comment: This looks like a bigger problem.  The Donation Table.xlsm was exported by Access 2007 as the result of a query; data stored in "DonationDataQuery" sheet.  Noticed that all number fields had a green triangle - numbers stored as text.  This was necessary as the data was being input by visually impaired persons.  Now when I try to open the sheet and fix the text to number issue, using code added above, it stops at "Range("A1:O50").Select" with error 1004...now will have to post another question  :(

Comment: Does the sheet have a limited number of columns? I can't see why `Range("A1:O50").Select` would fail unless your sheet doesn't have a cell `"O50"`, which I don't think is possible, or if somehow selection isn't possible (i.e. the sheet has lost focus)...

Comment: Thanks for the input...I was trying to open another file and run some code in that file, copy the results, and bring it back into my current workbook...too much trouble so just copied the data and closed the file, then pasted into current workbook and manipulated the data in the current workbook....problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

From your errors, I'd assume your code is in a worksheet code module and therefore all your Range and Cells calls refer to that sheet unless qualified with a worksheet object. Try this instead:

```
Dim Lastrow               As Long
Dim NumPickups            As Long
Dim rFound                As Range

With Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\dads\Downloads\Donation Data.xlsm").Worksheets("DonationDataQuery")

    Set rFound = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If rFound Is Nothing Then
        Lastrow = 2
    Else
        Lastrow = rFound.Row
    End If

    NumPickups = Lastrow - 1

    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Lastrow, 22)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("test.xlsm").ActiveSheet.Range("J1")

End With
```